# what is difference between structure image and texture image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am working in Computer Vision. One thing is confusing me, the difference between structure image and texture image. Both are looking same. but i read few papers, which showing that both are different. Someone tell me how they are different, and how can we said either this is structural or textural, or either both.

Comment: Your question has beeen answered. Do not hesitate to vote for the useful ones and accept the most suitable

Answer (score 2):

There is a growing awareness that images are not homogeneous and that it could be useful to model them as a combinaison or superposition of morphological components that have distinct properties. One can cite four main components: piecewise-smooth parts, contours, geometrical/periodic textures and a last one, barely modelled, sometimes termed noise.

The edge-cartoon/texture is a common name given to a more macroscopic version with two components: structure and texture. **Structure** often refers to the piecewise-smooth parts and large-scale contours, **texture** to geometrical and almost periodic textures, noise. Sometimes, they are called **geometry** and **oscillatory** components. Related works are mentioned in [Structure-Texture Image Decomposition](ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam05-10.pdf): See for instance: [Image decomposition toolbox](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/nelly.pustelnik/logicielE.html)

[image: Image decomposition toolbox, DTT (Dual-Tree Transform) texture coefficients and a total variation term to penalize the geometric component]

When the contours of an object are not distinct, its textural aspect can help to segment it. The color aspect is often put on the "texture" side.